# Tensorflow: Data dependent loss function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, loss-function

I am trying to implement a loss function that computes a loss depending on the (unaugmented) data.
So far I found an example detailing the process using the `model.add_loss()` method of a `tf.keras.models.Model()` [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/38353), but I struggle to implement it.

I have a `tf.Dataset` object containing my data, labels, and the data dependent variable for every sample calculated before augmentation (let's call it z). The data dependent variable is what I want to pass to my custom loss function.

I am dropping the ball in trying to pass the predictions, label and z to my loss function when calling it with `model.add_loss`.

Given a simple model like:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss
import numpy as np
 
data = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
label = Input(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float32)
z = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)

out = Dense(3)(data)

m = Model(inputs=[data, label, z], outputs=out)

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred, z):
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
    cce_loss = cce(y_true, y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(cce_loss, z))
  
m.add_loss(my_loss(label, out, z))
 
m.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam')

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1, 2, 3], [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]))

m.fit(dataset, epochs=10)
```

Trying to run this, I get:  `ValueError: Layer "model_17" expects 3 input(s), but it received 1 input tensors.`

Is there a way to use an input array [data, label, z] with a tf.dataset object? Or how do I access the three different values inside the model, if I just pass the dataset object as one input value?

Comment: You should pass 3 different arrays to tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(data_input, label_input, z_input), based on the shape defined in keras `Input` layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the ways to accomplish that is to use the `zip` function from `tf.data.Dataset` ([Reading more on TensorFlow website](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset#zip)). Here is the modified code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, Input
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.losses import Loss
import numpy as np
 
data = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)
label = Input(shape=(3,), dtype=tf.float32)
z = Input(shape=(1,), dtype=tf.float32)

out = Dense(3)(data)

m = Model(inputs=[data, label, z], outputs=out)

def my_loss(y_true, y_pred, z):
    cce = tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.NONE)
    cce_loss = cce(y_true, y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.multiply(cce_loss, z))
  
m.add_loss(my_loss(label, out, z))
m.compile(loss=None, optimizer='adam')

#original code:
#dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(([1, 2, 3], [[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]], [0.1, 0.2, 0.3]))

#----------------------------------------------
# modified code
#----------------------------------------------
inp_data=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([1, 2, 3])
inp_label=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([[1, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 1]])
inp_z=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices([0.1, 0.2, 0.3])

"""
Making a dummy `y` for dataset even though it is not used here due to having `loss=None`. 
Note that `inp_label` from input is still passed to the `add_loss` method.
"""
target = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(tf.zeros(3))

input_zip = tf.data.Dataset.zip((inp_data, inp_label, inp_z))
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.zip((input_zip, target))

dataset = dataset.batch(3)
#----------------------------------------------

m.fit(dataset, epochs=3)
```

Output:
[image]

---

**Note**

It is important to examine the code as well as the model architecture carefully to ensure the desired functionality is implemented correctly.
One of the helpful tools is the `plot_model` function from `tf.keras.utils`:

```
tf.keras.utils.plot_model(
    m,
    to_file='model.png',
    show_shapes=True,
    show_layer_names=True,
)
```

Output:
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Nesting the datasets in this way is a very clever work around, that I did not find anywhere when researching this topic.